# Allow to the user select two radio buttons in a group at the same time WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I am doing a WPF application and I need to allow the user to select exactly two radio buttons that belong to the same group.

Comment: Make them checkboxes as Joe C suggests, or the user will not understand that two may be selected. Bind them all to different viewmodel properties, and have the viewmodel enforce that a maximum of two may be checked at once.

Answer (score 0):

Radio buttons do not work that way.  You will have to use checkboxes and using the click event make sure that they do not choose more than two.